# this.find not working as expected with multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has multiple forms that enable image uploading. The forms are added dynamically so I cant use different id's. I want to trigger clicking the submit button on 'change', so when a user clicks the select button of chosen files. All works fine, but I cant seem to target just the current form. Here's what I have so far

The form

```
<form id="my_uploader" name="my_uploader">
      <label><?php __('Select Files:', 'cvf-upload'); ?>  </label> 
      <label class="fileContainer">Upload files <input accept="image/*" class="input-button" multiple name="files[]" type="file"></label> 
      <input class="btn-upload" type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Jquery

```
 $("body").on("change", "#my_uploader", function() {
    $(this).find(".btn-upload").click(); 
 });
```

At the moment this triggers all forms instead of just the one required.

Comment: `I cant use different id's`, why?

Comment: @btzr Is there a way to do this without using different id's, as In can you see an obvious reason why the .find isn't working

Comment: also you should use `submit` instead of `click`: `form.submit()`

Comment: `$(this).find(".currentForm").submit(); `

Comment: Create a code snippet to demonstrate the issue... because I just tested with multiple forms, and only the one that was interacted with was submitted, given that `$(this)` is the instance of `#my_uploader` that triggered the event.  I think you may have an issue unrelated to the code you've provided.

Comment: I'm also curious as to how you can trigger the submit of multiple forms, as soon as the browser submits the first form, all subsequent processing should halt (the browser will load the response document) - so you're definitely missing some additional information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you let the ids be and refer to the element by class?

Also, I believe I wasn't able to clarify to you that the reason why it didn't work was because the `onchange` event you required needed to be bound to `<input type="file">` **and not the form itself**.

This is because you actually intend to capture events **AFTER selecting at least one file** from

`<input accept="image/*" class="input-button target" multiple name="files[]" type="file">`

**Remember to un-comment** the actual command.

`$(this).closest('form').` looks for the first `<form>` parent of ***this*** element from inside out.

**We are now in the root** of `<form>` so we...

`.find(".btn-upload")` **and finally**...

`.click();` **on it.**

```js
// Event binding for dynamically created elements
// Generally placed outside document.ready
$(document).on( 'change' , '.target' , function (event) {

console.log( 'Handler for .change() called.' );
//$(this).closest( 'form' ).find( '.btn-upload' ).click();

console.log( $( this ).closest( 'form' ).find( '.btn-upload' ).val() + ' button clicked.' );

});

// Event binding for document.ready elements
$( '.target' ).change(function() {

console.log( 'Handler for .change() called.' );

//$(this).closest( 'form' ).find( '.btn-upload' ).click();
console.log( $( this ).closest( 'form' ).find( '.btn-upload' ).val() + ' button clicked.' );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>

<label class="fileContainer">Upload files
<input accept="image/*" class="input-button target" multiple name="files[]" type="file">
</label> 

<input class="btn-upload" type="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. What's the difference of using a class for to refer to the element, should the above not work by using the id. Thanks

Comment: Ids are intended to be unique. If you create this function by id you will have to create a function each id.

Comment: Okay gotchya, Ive tried it by using with class like you've suggested and still not working. No error in console, but just nothing runs. Where as by using the id before, it ran.. just targeted every form instead of just the one

Comment: Or alternitevly an each function would be fine, how can I tweak my code so create an Each and change function together.